# How to use shape key value in scripted expression driver?

Tags: drivers, shape-keys

I have two objects, *mesh A* and *mesh B*, where *mesh B* has a *shape key* named ***shape-change*** with a value range of 0 to 1.
I added a driver to the rotation `Z` property of *mesh A* which should make it rotate when the value of the shape key of *mesh B* changes. How do I implement the driver script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much more simple solution would be:

1. Select "object b", over shape key *Value*, right mouse click and *Copy as New Driver*

[image]

2. Select "object a", *Rotation Z* value and *Paste Driver*

[image]

3. Now change driver settings to *Scripted Expression* and change expression to `value*2*pi`

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's the way! Thanks!

Comment: awesome! that's good to know that there is paste driver. but for some reason it does not paste it correctly in my blender 3.1. i get path "active_shape_key_index" but i see in your path you get "keyblock... something"

Comment: @FransonWu can you confirm what value you get in `Path` after you do Paste Driver? I only get `active_shape_key_index` so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I get this " key_blocks["Key 1"].value ", works.  Blender version 3.0.1.

Comment: @FransonWu thank you for checking. That's really odd. I also checked on 2.93, 3.0, 3.1 and it also doesn't work. Maybe because i'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Follow my setup: make sure *object A* is named ***mesh-obj-a*** and its mesh is named ***mesh-a*** and *object B* is named ***mesh-obj-b*** and its mesh is named ***mesh-b***. Also make sure that *object B* has a shape key under *Shape Keys* named ***shape-change***

Now, there's two ways to do this. The first method or easy way is to execute this python script in the *Text Editor* and you're done.

```
import bpy

obj_a = bpy.data.objects['mesh-obj-a']
obj_b = bpy.data.objects['mesh-obj-b']

drivers = obj_a.animation_data.drivers
for d in drivers:  
    obj_a.driver_remove(d.data_path, -1)

fcurve = obj_a.driver_add("rotation_euler", 2)
d = fcurve.driver

v = d.variables.new()
v.name = "keys"

target = v.targets[0]
target.id_type = 'MESH'
target.id = obj_b.data
target.data_path = "shape_keys"

d.expression = "radians(keys.key_blocks['shape-change'].value*360)"
```

The second method is the manual way by doing the following:

Select *object A* and right click its `Rotation Z` property in the *Object Properties* and select ***Add Driver***

[image]

Click the `X` icon to delete the default input variable and click ***Add Input Variable***. Change the variable name from *var* to ***keys***. Then change the *ID-Block type* from *Object* to *Mesh* and select the mesh *mesh-b*

[image]

In the *Expression* field input the following script which converts the shape key value `0-1` to `0-360` as radians (0.0174533 is the factor for degrees to radians conversion):

```
keys.key_blocks['shape-change'].value*360*0.0174533
```

or better:

```
radians(keys.key_blocks['shape-change'].value*360)
```

In the *Path* field, input the value ***shape_keys***

[image]

Now when you change the value of the shape key of object B from 0 to 1, it will drive or rotate object A on the z-axis from 0 to 360 degrees.

[image]

Comment: Cool! Many thanks!

Comment: you're welcome! glad it worked out :)